# Syntax for returning an array reference in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, function, reference, declaration

I have been brushing up on array concepts in C++, when I came across this question: [Return an array in c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2302279/return-an-array-in-c)

Someone answered using this declaration:

```
int (&f(int (&arr)[3]))[3]
```

What I can't seem to grasp is the [3] after the closing parenthesise. I've never seen a function declaration that looked like this. I understand the rest of the syntax, but I don't particularly understand how the [3] works because it is after the function name. I apologize in advance if I'm overlooking something simple. I also tried looking at the spec for function declarations but I didn't see anything related that I could link to the subscript syntax. So, how is this possible?

Comment: Because K & R are sadists.

Comment: http://cdecl.org/. C declarator syntax can be "fun".

Comment: Once you get it, please never ever write such horrible thing in a real life code.

Comment: Use the power of c++11: http://cpp.sh/76dc

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The function is returning a *reference* to an array of `int` of size `3` and the `[3]` part after the function actually the size of the array to be returned as *reference*.

This obscure syntax comes from the weird syntax of array declaration, which you do as:

```
int arr[3]; //real but weird
```

The language would have been much simpler if it had this instead:

```
int[3] arr; //hypothetical but better and simpler
```

because size `3` is *part* of the type of `arr`, so it makes much more sense if all the parts appear on the left side of the variable name, in the same way as when you write:

```
unsigned int a;
```

You dont write:

```
unsigned a int; //analogous to : int a [3];
```

So while the language does the right thing with `unsigned int`, it does a very weird thing with `int[3]`.

Now coming back to the function declaration, the function would have been much better if it is declared as:

```
int[3]& f(int[3]& arr); //hypothetical
```

only if it had all the parts on the left side of variable-name. But since it doesn't do that (i.e the language *requires* you to write the size on the rightmost side after the variable name), you end up with this weird signature:

```
int (&f(int (&arr)[3])[3]; //real
```

Notice that how even the parameter becomes weird.

---

But you can simplify it with a typedef as:

```
typedef int array_type[3];

array_type& f(array_type& arr);
```

That looks much better. Now only the *typedef* looks weird.

With C++11, you can write even a better typedef:

```
using array_type = int[3];

array_type& f(array_type& arr);
```

which is as close as this (if you visualize `array_type` as `int[3]`):

```
int[3]& f(int[3]& arr); //hypothetical
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This all makes sense now.

Answer (score 3):

Well, read this [article](http://csapp.cs.cmu.edu/3e/docs/chistory.html) about C history, by its creator Dennis M. Ritchie.

Looks like this syntax we got from B, thru C to C++...

I believe, this way of declaring several variables of some "basic type" is a root of this strange syntax:

```
int a, *b, c[3];
```

So `a` is just `int`, `b` is pointer to `int` and `c` is array of `int`...

If these `*` and `[3]` would be part of type definition not a variable definition - then we would need 3 lines to write this:

```
int a;
int* b;
int[3] c;
```

---

There are two good resources on [SO C page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info) to learn how to parse such constructions:

- [The Clockwise/Spiral Rule for parsing C declarations.](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)
- [cdecl: C gibberish ↔ English, a site that translate C expressions to readable English](http://cdecl.ridiculousfish.com/).

cdecl is failing a little - because references are not part of C - so let's try with [The Clockwise/Spiral Rule for parsing C declarations.](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html)

```
int (&f(int (&arr)[3]))[3]
```

1. `arr` -> arr
2. `&arr` -> arr is reference
3. `(&arr)` -> arr is reference - surrounding `()` not really change a thing
4. `(&arr)[3]` -> arr is reference to array of size 3
5. `int (&arr)[3]` -> arr is reference to array of size 3 of type int

Next:

1. `f` -> f
2. `f(int (&arr)[3])` -> f is function taking arr, which is ...
3. `&f(int (&arr)[3])` -> f is function taking arr, which is ..., and returning reference
4. `(&f(int (&arr)[3]))[3]` -> f is function taking arr, which is ..., and returning reference to array of size 3
5. `int (&f(int (&arr)[3]))[3]` -> f is function taking arr, which is reference to array of size 3 of type int, and returning reference to array of size 3 of type int

Of course - this code shall be replaced with, at least for me, much easier to read version:

```
using int3 = int[3];
int3& f(int3& arr);
```

Comment: This makes sense. Thanks for the detailed answer!   The spiral rule will be very useful.

Answer (score 1):

```
int (&f (int (&arr)[3]) )[3]
{
    return arr;
}
```

Let's go from the inside. The `(int (&arr)[3])` part means that the function takes a reference to an int array of 3 elements as the parameter. This is the same `arr` that is being returned.

Now, the rest of the syntax saiys that the function should return a reference to an array of 3 ints. `f` is the function's name. `int &f()` would mean that you return a reference to an `int`, but you need to return an array of the fixed size, hence you should add the `[3]` The parenthesis around the `&f(...)` are used because in c++ you write the size of the array after the variable name, not after the type name, as Nawaz explains in his answer. If you omit those parenthesis, the compiler will interpret `f` as an array of references, as in `int & f[3]`.